# A bit confused on the relative pathnames started with ../

Tags: unix, relative-path, absolute-path

If my current working directory is `/usr/ecs036a/tmp`, then why the absolute pathname for `../src/./../passwd+/misc/./root.c` is `/usr/ecs036a/passwd+/misc/root.c`? I thought the `../` means you go to the root directory `/` already. Thanks!

Comment: No, `/` means the root directory. `..` means the parent directory.  So, from the perspective of your working directory, `..` is `/usr/ecs036a`. Note also that `.` is the "current" directory, so that part is unnecessarily redundant.

Comment: @ghoti so `/usr/ecs036a/tmp/../src/./../passwd+/misc/./root.c` is the same as `/usr/ecs036a/passwd+/misc/root.c` right?

Comment: Yes, UNLESS `src` is a symlink that takes you off someplace else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the root directory is `/`. `../` means the directory above.